# GitHub Workflow is not terminating

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase-realtime-database, es6-promise, github-actions

I have created a GitHub workflow which runs a node script,
to test it I made it to run on a manual trigger.
this is the code of my workfow file:

```
on:
   workflow_dispatch:
    inputs:
      logLevel:
        description: 'Log level'     
        required: true
        default: 'warning'
      tags:
        description: 'Test scenario tags'
```

this workflow runs a Node.js script which basically fetches data from Firebase real-time database and then posts data to Twitter.
The script is doing its job perfectly but the problem is that workflow is not terminating at all.
Once I have once manually triggered it, it worked properly but when I noticed after 25 minutes it didn't got terminated and was running for 25 min.

The workflow terminated when I just used only Twitter API but this problem started after I added Firebase code. Please help me.

Here is my code:

```js
db.once('value').then(snapshot=>{
    let v = snapshot.val();  
    let m = modifiyData(v);
    T.post(
        'statuses/update',
        { status: m },
        function (_err, data) {
            console.log( 'Successfully posted the tweet!',data );
        }
    )
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure to call [delete()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.app.App-1#delete) on the Firebase app object you previously initialized.  Only call this after you are completely done with it for the process.  As the API docs state:

> this method must be called to ensure graceful termination of the process